# How to access 'Private working set' in powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, memory-management, process

I am trying to get private working set of memory in the following code. Is it possible to do it?

```
Param(
    [ValidateSet("Pid","Name","CpuPercent","PrivateBytes","Description","ParentPid","SessionId","Handles","Threads","Path")]
    [string] $OrderBy = "Pid",
    $Descending = $false,
    [int] $Top = "99999",
    [ValidateSet("text","csv","json","list")]
    [string] $Format = "json"
)


Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"


$Desc = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($Descending);


$PoshProcesses = @(Get-Process)


Function Get-WmiProcPerfSample
{

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process -Filter 'IDProcess != 0' -Property IDProcess,CreatingProcessID,PercentProcessorTime,TimeStamp_Sys100NS,ElapsedTime
}


$WmiPerfData = @{}
$sampleSet1 = @{}
Get-WmiProcPerfSample | ForEach-Object {$sampleSet1[$_.IDProcess] = $_}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1


Foreach ($sample in Get-WmiProcPerfSample) {

    $procTime = $sample.PercentProcessorTime
    $timeWindow = ($sample.TimeStamp_Sys100NS - $sample.ElapsedTime)


    If ($sampleSet1.ContainsKey($sample.IDProcess))
    {
        $procTime = $sample.PercentProcessorTime - $sampleSet1[$sample.IDProcess].PercentProcessorTime
        $timeWindow = $sample.TimeStamp_Sys100NS - $sampleSet1[$sample.IDProcess].TimeStamp_Sys100NS
    }

    $WmiPerfData["$($sample.IDProcess)"] = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        "PID"=$sample.IDProcess;
        "CreatingProcessID"=$sample.CreatingProcessID;
        "PercentProcessorTime"=($procTime / $timeWindow) * 100 / [System.Environment]::ProcessorCount
    }
}

$OutputObjects= @();
foreach ($PoshProcess in $PoshProcesses)
{
    $WmiProcess = $WmiPerfData["$($PoshProcess.Id)"];
    if (-not $WmiProcess -or $PoshProcess.Id -eq 0) {
        continue;
    }


    $OutputObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Pid -Value $PoshProcess.Id
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $PoshProcess.Name
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CpuPercent -Value ([Math]::Round($WmiProcess.PercentProcessorTime, 2))
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PrivateBytes -Value $PoshProcess.PrivateMemorySize64
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $PoshProcess.Description
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ParentPid -Value $WmiProcess.CreatingProcessID
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SessionId -Value $PoshProcess.SessionId
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Handles -Value $PoshProcess.Handles
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Threads -Value $PoshProcess.Threads.Count
    Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $PoshProcess.Path

    $OutputObjects += $OutputObject
    $OutputObject = $Null
}



[System.Collections.ArrayList]$OutPutOrdering = $OutputObjects[0].psobject.Properties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$OutPutOrdering.Insert(0,$OrderBy)

$OutPutOrdering = $OutPutOrdering | Select-Object -Unique | Foreach-Object {$_.ToString()}

if ($Format -eq 'text')
{
    $OutputObjects `
        | Sort-Object -Property $OrderBy -Descending:$Desc `
        | Select-Object -First $Top -Property $OutPutOrdering -ExcludeProperty Path `
        | Format-Table -AutoSize `
        | Out-String -Width 4096 `
        | Write-Host
}
elseif ($Format -eq 'csv')
{
    $OutputObjects `
        | Sort-Object -Property $OrderBy -Descending:$Desc `
        | Select-Object -First $Top -Property $OutPutOrdering `
        | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation `
        | Out-String -Width 4096 `
        | Write-Host
}
elseif ($Format -eq 'json')
{
    $OutputObjects `
        | Sort-Object -Property $OrderBy -Descending:$Desc `
        | Select-Object -First $Top -Property $OutPutOrdering `
        | convertto-json `
        | Out-String -Width 4096 `
        | Write-Host
}
elseif ($Format -eq 'list')
{
    $OutputObjects `
        | Sort-Object -Property $OrderBy -Descending:$Desc `
        | Select-Object -First $Top -Property $OutPutOrdering -ExcludeProperty Path `
        | Format-List `
        | Out-String -Width 4096 `
        | Write-Host
}
```

I know we can get this by

```
(Get-Counter "\Process(*)\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples
```

But I want 'private working set' in my current code if possible as I also need my output in JSON. Is it possible to use Get-Counter at the same time for all pid? How can I achieve it in above code? If you know you can use other methods as well.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. What about your code doesn't work the way you expected? Do you need an additional column with the title "Private Working Set"? You could add that with another `Add-Member` statement. Also, please stick to one problem at a time. Don't mix different problems into one question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I just want the 'private working set' of memory in my code. Can you help me in getting it?

Comment: Does simply adding `Add-Member -InputObject $OutputObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Private Working Set' -Value (Get-Counter "\Process(*)\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples` not work?

Comment: 'Process(*)' will get all the processes. Is there any way to get it only for current PID? i.e $PoshProcess.Id. Process(AppName) we can Pass. But how can we pass processId in it?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers If I pass processId to Process(PID) I am getting an error.

Comment: If you take a look at the counter samples you'll see that the counters for indiviual processes can be accessed via `\Process(PROCESSNAME)\Working Set - Private`. However, if there are multiple processes of the same name, there's an index added to the name (`#1`, `#2`, ...). I'm not sure if those indicate the same order in which `Get-Process` returns the processes.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Exactly, I am not certain that this will work. I need something dependent on processId to make it certain.